# Series representation of $n$th derivative of $x^n/(1+x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, summation

> Find the nth derivative of $\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}$.

Please I need help in this. They are further asking to show that when $x=\cot y$ the nth derivative can be expressed as
$$n!\sin y\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r {n\choose r}\cos^r y\sin[(r+1)y]$$

My attempt
Since the function inside can be expressed as $P(x)-\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ or $P(x)-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ with
$\deg(P)=n-2$ as per $n$ is odd or even, I tried to write the nth derivative of the function as

$(-1)^n n! \cos(n+1)y \sin^{n+1} y$

or $(-1)^n n! \sin(n+1)y \sin^{n+1} y$

as and when n is odd or even and then tried induction to prove this equal to the R.H.S , obviously cancelling out the $n!$. But at that induction step I am getting entangled. Though i showed this holds for n=1,2.

Comment: The [general Leibniz rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) is used and substituting $y=\cot^{-1}(x)$ will get you the $n$th derivative in terms of $x$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Leibnitz, but in got complicated

Comment: @TymaGaidash can u please elaborate i tried but complicated the steps...

Comment: As an intermediate step, it may be worth converting from the desired series representation back to $x$, via $(\cos y,\sin y)=(x/\sqrt{x^2+1},1/\sqrt{x^2+1}).$

Comment: @Semiclassical But what to do with the $\sin (r+1)y$ ? That is the main problem...

Comment: Applying the generalized Leibniz rule to the $n$th derivative of $x^n f(x)$ with $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ does yield $$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}\frac{n!}{r!}x^r f^{(r)}(x).$$ This puts the problem in the desired series form and reduces the question to finding all the derivatives of $f(x)$. But it's not clear to me how to proceed further.